# Make CSS and jQuery function results persist on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am in the process of adding adding css that turns font red when it is clicked. The clicked event is being called on a jQuery function. When a persons name is clicked, I am able to make the font to turn red but when I refresh the page, the red font goes back to normal and the css/jQuery is no longer working. Can someone help me figure out how to make the css/jQuery persist even on page refresh. I want to red font to turn back to normal only if a user clicks on it again.

HTML/PHP

```
<td>
  <span id="nameSpan" class="EmpName"><strong>
       //Pulling in the name I want to click on
       <?php echo $data['EmpName']; ?></strong></span>
</td>
```

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.EmpName').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.clicked{
    font: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: You need to store that state somwhere, e.g. in cookies, `localStorage`, in page address, or on server via AJAX call.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? Which method is most simplistic?

Comment: Cookie or `localStorage` would be simplest. Not sure re example.

Comment: Am I setting a cookie with JS or PHP?

Comment: Both ways could do, but with PHP is a longest one -- via AJAX call. BTW, your CSS is invalid, probably you wanted to write `color: red;`.

Comment: Yes sorry, wrote it wrong it should be color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use localStorage/cookies to store the value. Here is an example for using localStorage.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ls = window.localStorage;
    var storeKey = 'item-clicked';

    $('.EmpName').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        if(ls)
        {
            var clicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
            ls.setItem(storeKey, clicked ? 1 : 0);
        }
    });

    var clicked = ls ? parseInt(ls.getItem(storeKey)) === 1 : false;
    if(clicked)
    {
        $('.EmpName').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: this line (clicked ? 1 : 0);) gives me an error of "Argument type number is not assignable to parameter type string". When I click on the EmpName, they no longer turn red. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry, change it to clicked ? '1' : '0'

Comment: Okay so when I click one name and then refresh, upon page refresh...every name is now turning red.

Comment: Everything works well other then the fact that when I refresh the page, every name is turning red without being clicked. :)

Comment: OH, you may need to change the code to store the id of item, then after refreshing you pick the elements with the ids which are stored then change them to red.

Comment: How do you mean? Would I use the nameSpan id that I set on span?

Comment: This works really well. The only issue I am having now is that I am only able to save one name as red on page refresh. My guess is because the id is remaining the same in the HTML fields regardless of which name is passed in. So in your fiddle you have different id's of "id="nameSpan1", id="nameSpan2" etc. but my id will always be nameSpan since the names are being populated in one spot by the PHP. Do you know a work around for this?

Comment: id must be unique in a page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id. 

If you are using a loop to generate the td node in php code, you can init a variable outside the loop, like `$id_index = 1;`, then in the loop `<td>
  <span id="nameSpan<?php echo $id_index ++; ?>" class="EmpName"><strong>
       //Pulling in the name I want to click on
       <?php echo $data['EmpName']; ?></strong></span>
</td>`